# Converting book into database easily (XML?)

Tags: xml, database

### Aim

I'm a historian. In my project we want to digitize a book which is a collection of data about various historical localities: various names in different languages, archeological information, bibliography. We wanto to transform a book into a database as we want to make connections between places and ultimately project the results on a map using QGIS. We would like to avoid copy-pasting the book to MS Access or similar software entry by entry.

### Idea

I had an idea that we tag the text of the book with XML tags (`<place_name>`, `<location>`, `<archaeological_excavations>` and so on). Then these perhaps could be automatically or semi-automatically transformed into a simple database or spreadsheet which we would then further develop.

### Question

1. Is this possible? I was looking online for ways to do it (”xml tags to database” and similar search queries). I found nothing. Perhaps I should type for something more specific?
2. Perhaps there is a better way to do it? We have the .docx version of the book.

I have little experience with coding and digital humanities, but I'm willing to learn something new in order to get this done.

Comment: https://xquery.forhumanists.org/ might help setting up XML databases like BaseX, for content I guess look for introductions to TEI.

Comment: https://oxgarage2.tei-c.org/ might help converting from docx to TEI